# Make Trigger Bool variable

Tags: c#, triggers, boolean

is there any easy algorithm to get run at first time in a method ( for example in this example we call it example() )

```
    private bool trigger
    private int timer=0;

    public void main()
    {
       for (int i =0;i<5;i++){

          if (trigger==false)
               Console.WriteLine("loading...");
          else
               Console.WriteLine("hello world");
          example() 
       }
    }
public void example() 
   {
      if (timer==0)
           {
             //my loading data , like define value to variable or any thing else
             trigger = true ; // define a example variable trigger;
           }
        else
            {
            // after loading data do it at runtime
            trigger = false ;
            }
        timer++;

   }
```

Comment: What is being asked here?  What is a "void under process"?

Comment: You can write that if this way: `trigger = timer++ == 0;` but it won't solve anything, really.

Comment: sorry i dont chek my types  - ( Void main )  when Void main is under processing -  i want trigger work and when Void main is down  my trigger was reset (thanks alot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use static variables in class

```
public class trigger
{


      static bool isTriggered = false;
      static int timer = 0;

      public static void main()
      {//not a console app-- main used cause op used it

          if (timer==0) isTriggered=true;               
          else istriggered=false; 

          timer++;//happens no matter what

      }
}
```

this could be meaningful with event...  lets try it!

```
public class trigger
{          
      static int timer = 0;          

       //events
      public static event EventHandler<TriggerEventArgs> Trigger;
      static void onTrigger(object sender, TriggerEventArgs e){if(Trigger != null)Trigger(sender,e);}

      public static void main()// <--- no args?
      {//not a console app-- main used cause op used it


          if (timer==0)onTrigger(new object(),new TriggerEventArgs(/*stuff could go here*/));

          /*
          else
             istriggered=false; 
          */

          timer++;//happens no matter what
          //increment your life away

      }
}

public class TriggerEventArgs : EventArgs
{

  //what ever you could possibly need and more 
  //TODO: add constructor so /*stuff can go here*/

}
```

then use in initialization function in your project like

```
void initializefunc()
{
     trigger.Trigger += subscription;
}

void subscription(object sender, TriggerEventArgs e)
{
    //meaningful code
}
```

or well I suppose you could overload ++ operator (full code example)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {//the real console app

        //test the strange trigger class
        trigger.Trigger += trigger_Trigger;
        trigger t = new trigger();
        trigger a = new trigger();

        for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
        {
            t++;
            a++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void trigger_Trigger(object sender, TriggerEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("once");
    }
}

public class trigger
{
    static int timer = 0;

    //standard event pattern  (static style)
    public static event EventHandler<TriggerEventArgs> Trigger;
    static void onTrigger(object sender, TriggerEventArgs e) { if (Trigger != null)Trigger    (sender, e); }


    //overload the ++ operator
    public static trigger operator ++ (trigger t)
    {
        trigger.ops_main();//yeah.. i know this is kinda strange
        //but so is the question
        return t;
    }



    public static void ops_main()// <--- no args?
    {//not a console app-- main used cause op used it


        if (timer == 0) onTrigger(new object(), new TriggerEventArgs());

        /*
        else
           istriggered=false; 
        */

        timer++;//happens no matter what
        //increment your life away

    }
}

public class TriggerEventArgs : EventArgs
{

  //what ever you could possibly need and more 

}   


}
```

Comment: I know it was not worth it. but I got inspired.

Comment: Thanks alot - you help me full ( you teaching me all tip of Classes and i find A clean Way to make Trigger) your code works good (but i change a little it >:D< i dont remember your helping (i dont sleep for it :D)

Comment: anytime. -- now go get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Does seem a bit weird what you are doing, but the simple answer is to change your 0 and 1 to true and false

```
private bool trigger
private int timer;

public void main()
{
    if (timer==0)
        trigger=true;
    else
        trigger=false;
    timer++;
}
```

Comment: is not goood way for Big programming  project  ( I write A strategic AI and use it alot ) is type of variable (like int like Bool or.. ) can do this (whit tiny code)

Comment: Then I am sorry if I misunderstood the question, it isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Chris im sorry for bad questioning - i think making a class for it is only way to solve this problem :-? (Bye the way tanks) i want vote up u for helping but my point is very down ) have good times